# In infinite dimensional vector spaces the complementary of a compact is connected

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, compactness, normed-spaces, path-connected

Let $X$ be an infinite dimensional normed vector space and $K$ a compact subset of $X$. I want to show that $K^c$ is connected by path. I know that the unity sphere $\mathbb{S} := S(0,1)$ is connected by path and that up to an homeomorphism I can assume $K \subset \mathbb{B} := B(0,1)$. So I only need to find a path from $x$ to a certain $u \in \mathbb{S}$, for any $x \in K^c$. I was suggested to look at the easiest paths, $t \mapsto (1-t)x+tu$, but I fail to conclude. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Think about what it would mean if none of those "easiest paths" work.

Comment: I'm not sure what's wrong with the procedure you proposed.  I'd probably take the u to be the point x/|x|.  Given any two points x,x' in the complement, consider the paths from x to u = x/|x| and from x' to u' = x' / |x'|, then connect those two points by a path on the sphere.

Comment: @cjohnson: The paths to $u$ and $u'$ may not be contained in $K^c$.

Comment: @EricWofsey Ah, okay.  I think I was making some silly assumptions.  Now I'm confused about whether this statement is true though.  The statement is certainly false in finite dimensions?  E.g., if K was the unit sphere then its inside and outside are two connected components.  I don't see why the same isn't a counterexample in infinitely-many dimensions.

Comment: @EricWofsey if none would work, for any $u \in \mathbb{S}$ I can find $t(u) \in (0,1)$ such that $(1-t(u))x+t(u)u \in K$. Denoting $f(u)$ the last vector I get an injection from $\mathbb{S}$ to $K$ but is has no reason to be continuous. To me it has neither no reason to preserve the lake of totally boundness.

Comment: @cjohnson in finite dimension it is not true because the unity sphere is compact and its complementary has two connected components.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If none of the paths $t\mapsto (1-t)x+tu$ are contained in $K^c$, then for each $u\in\mathbb{S}$ there exists a point of the form $(1-t)x+tu$ in $K$.  In other words, if you could define a continuous map $f:\mathbb{B}\setminus\{x\}\to\mathbb{S}$ that takes $(1-t)x+tu$ to $u$ (geometrically, "project away from $x$ until you hit $\mathbb{S}$") then $f$ would be surjective restricted to $K$ and so $\mathbb{S}$ would be compact, giving a contradiction.

Probably you can do a bit of work to prove this map $f$ is well-defined and continuous.  You can avoid any of that work by ending the argument a different way, though.  In the special case that $x=0$, then $f$ is just the map $v\mapsto v/\|v\|$ which is obviously well-defined and continuous.  So, if you take an arbitrary point $x\in K^c$ and translate it to $0$, this shows that there exists a path in $K^c$ from $x$ to some point in any given sphere centered around $x$.  In particular, taking that sphere to have sufficiently large radius, this gives a path from $x$ to a point that is outside of the ball $\mathbb{B}$.  Since $X\setminus\mathbb{B}$ is path-connected, this completes the proof.

Comment: I don't see how $f$ is defined from $\mathbb{B} \setminus \{x \}$, to me it is defined from $\mathbb{S}$. Even if $x = 0$ I think you assume that, using my notations, $\{ (1-t(u)))x+t(u)u \} = K$ which I see no reason to be true.

Comment: When $x=0$ it is completely trivial.  If $v\in\mathbb{B}\setminus\{0\}$, then $u=v/\|v\|$ is a unit vector and $v=tu$ where $t=\|v\|$, and this is the unique way to write $v=tu$ where $u$ is a unit vector and $t\in[0,1]$.

Comment: Ok I see the point, thanks. Is there any intelligible way to see how considering $y \mapsto y/||y||$ is profitable?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that.

Comment: Why did you consider $y \mapsto y/||y||$ ?

Comment: Well, it's the simplest and most natural map to $\mathbb{S}$ to consider, if you're looking to use the fact that $\mathbb{S}$ is not compact.  It takes a vector and just normalizes it to get a unit vector in the same direction.